# Socket.io and local storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, socket.io, local-storage

I have made a chat app using socket.io and node.

- **Scenario-** Now need to store messages into localStorage of browser , just before socket gets disconnected (disconnect event is emited) and fetch / sync data to that local storage once user reconnects.
- **Issue-** But problem is that if I am emiting some event from inside of "disconnect" handler back to client and there on client side inside handler for this event `localStorage.setItem('msgText', msg)`. Its not saving to local storage.(As on disconnect event client has already been disconnected)
- Used `node-localstorage` module to set data in local storage of browser, while painting view when user logs-in , but its not saving data to localStorage of browser

`const LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage
  let localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch')
localStorage.setItem('name_test', 'tom')
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('name_test'))`

***Any suggestion , as how to tackle the scenario / issue is most appreciated on this ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fire the `disconnect` event, you could set your local storage just before. If I am understanding correctly I believe the below example should work for you

```
function disconnectUserFromChat() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
      localStorage.setItem('key', 'Value')
      resolve()
    } catch(error) {
      reject(error)
    }
  })
})

disconnectUserFromChat()
  .then(function() {
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      console.log('Disconnected')
    })
  })
```

Comment: Thanks Jack , but `disconnect` event is fired automatically from client side when tab is closed . We cann't fire that event from app

Comment: ** Edit for above ** Thanks Jack , but `disconnect` is a reserved event which is fired automatically from client side when socket is disconnected or closed . We cann't fire that event from app

Comment: Have you looked at the `window.onbeforeunload` event? You can put your localstorage logic inside this event & it will save before it exits. Here's the docs on it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload